# Spring security custom UserDetails not authenticating

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, mockmvc

while experimenting around with spring boot, security, and data.

i just came across this scenario:

i use H2 in memory DB and poblate it with one user with liquibase on startup
with username and password.

now i want spring security to authenticate against H2. for that purpose i have this code:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImp);
 }
```

and im implementing the userDetails as follows:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
//this works, the user with pass is pulled
    com.fix.demo.logic.user.User byUsername = 
userRepository.findByUsername(username); 
    if (byUsername == null) {
        System.out.println("No user found with username: ");
        return null; //trow ex here
    }
    User user = new User(byUsername.getUsername(),
            byUsername.getPassword(), true, true,
            true, true, getAuthorities(Collections.singletonList("user")));
    //System.out.println(user.toString());
    //System.out.println(byUsername.toString()+ "   "+byUsername.getPassword());
        return user;
    }
```

but my tests keep failing with

> Authentication should not be null

and trying to log in will give me

> bad credentials

what is necessary for my custom implementation of UserDetailsService to work?

this is the failing test:

```
@Test
public void loginWithValidUserThenAuthenticated() throws Exception {
    FormLoginRequestBuilder login = formLogin()
            .user("admin")
            .password("root");

    mockMvc.perform(login)
            .andExpect(authenticated().withUsername("admin"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons is, the password might my encoded and you need to tell spring security to use an encoder. Add the following line to the configure override.

```
auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
```

define the passwordEncoder bean.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Comment: but i am not saving an encoded password on H2. i am saving it just as admin, root

Comment: based on your answer i made a custom password encoder, which does not encode the password but just compares them as clear text. and now its working